# "Selected list of publications" or "List of selected publications"?

Tags: idiomatic-language, phrase-choice

When we talk about a list of best publications on some topic, what is the proper way to call it?

"Selected publications" ​sounds fine, but in my particular case I need to include the word "list".

So whether it should be (1) "Selected list of publications" or (2) "List of selected publications"?

The second version makes more sense to my opinion, but it seems it is used mostly on German, Indian, Russian, and Brazil sites, and isn't really popular on US or UK ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"***A*** selected list of publications" means there are several different lists of publications, and you're selecting one of them.

"***A*** list of selected publications" means there are several publications, and you're selecting some of them and putting them into a list.

Since you haven't specified how the selection is made, I can't tell you which to choose, but the second one seems more likely.